# css height issue. I have a section element with a fixed height, I want the ol to take the rest of the height which varies

Tags: css, html

I have the following html

```
<section>
  <header>some controls in here</header>
  <ol>varying number of <li></ol>
<section>
```

and the following css

```
section { height: 300px, max-height: 600px}
```

I'm not setting a height on the header. It's auto by default or perhaps inherit.  Anyways how can I get the OL to take up the remaining height of the container.  I have tried auto and it doesn't seem to work.  Any ideas or tips are greatly appreciated. Note the section element can be resized vertically.  the header will remain constant, but I want the ol to take the remainder of the container height. I think I can accomplish with javascript but I'm looking for a pure css solution this time. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score -1):

Pure CSS solution:

```
section ol li { height: 100 / [number of <li> elements] % }
```

i.e. if the `<li>` elements are 4:

```
section ol li { height: 25% }
```

Works, I've tested it.

Comment: He said he's got a dynamic amount of li's in th ol

Comment: Sorry, I just can't see a better solution